# Mysql Import for tables with engine type HEAP

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

I have a sql file export of a older mysql ver. 4  which has a couple of tables listed as HEAP... When I try to import the file into a mysql ver. 5 database , the HEAP tables now show engine type as MEMORY...

I do see the records for these tables after the import, however the size of the table is now reported as unknown...

Also, I see that the end result of the import shows a lesser number of records than in the original database( records for HEAP  tables are not being counted) and the overall database size as 0 mb...

Should I be worried about anything or is this import valid  and workable?

Just to add  I used phpmyadmin both for import and export...

Answer (score 0):

Formerly, Memory store engine's tables were known as HEAP tables in old versions of mysql. MEMORY is the preferred term, although HEAP remains supported for backward compatibility.

The MEMORY storage engine associates each table with one disk file. The file name begins with the table name and has an extension of .frm to indicate that it stores the table definition.

They are size 0 because they haven't been requested by the server for itself internal operations.

So far you have nothing to be worried about. But, of course, always keep your backups. ;-)